# Issue with client-session middleware: req.session_state = undefined after being set

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, session-cookies

I've hit a bit of a problem getting client-session middleware working in Express. In short the session_state doesn't seem to be accessible when redirecting to new route after being set. For reference I have followed [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvviEA1pOXw) (client-session part starts 36:00 approx.) and double checked my steps but still encountering problems. Middleware is set up as follows:

```
var sessions = require('client-sessions');
```

Instantiated with code from the Express website.

```
app.use(sessions({
 cookieName: 'session',
 secret: 'iljkhhjfebxjmvjnnshxhgoidhsja', 
 duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
 activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5 
}));
```

I have the sessions middleware placed between bodyParser and routes if that makes any difference.

Here are the sections my `routes/index.js` pertaining to the issue. The `req.session_state` seems to get set ok and the correct user details log to the console.

```
// POST login form
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne( { email: req.body.email }, function(err,user){
    if(!user) {
      console.log("User not found...");
      res.render('login.jade', 
         { message: 'Are you sure that is the correct email?'} );
    } else {
        if(req.body.password === user.password) {

        // User gets saved and object logs correctly in the console
            req.session_state = user;
            console.log("session user...", req.session_state);

            res.redirect('/dashboard'); 
        }
    }
    //res.render('login.jade', { message: 'Invalid password'} );
  });
});
```

However, something is going wrong when the `res.redirect('/dashboard');` is run because the session_state is not accessible when it hits that route. Here is the code for the `/dashboard` route.

```
router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {

   // OUTPUT = 'undefined' ???
   console.log("dash...", req.session_state);

   // 'if' fails and falls through to /login redirect
   if(req.session && req.session_state){
       console.log("dash route...", req.session_state);
       User.findOne( { email: req.session_state.email }, function
        (err, user){
         if(!user){
            req.session.reset();
            res.redirect('/login');
         } else {
            res.locals.user = user;
            res.render('dashboard.jade')
         }
      });
   } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
   }
   //res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Your Dashboard' });
});
```

Basically, the object stored in session_state is not accessible after the `/dashboard` redirect. I've been trying to debug it for a day or so without any luck. Any help much appreciated. Sorry if I am missing something obvious. Just getting my feet wet with session middleware so maybe I haven't fully grasped Session or I am overlooking something. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my answer with code that should help you set the cookie and an alternative session manager known as a token. In this example I've provided to parts to a middle ware one part which attaches the cookie (this can be expanded on to determine your use case) and the second part which checks the token for expiration or what ever else might be in there (i.e. audience, issuer, etc.)

```
 app.use('/js/',function(req, res, next) {
//check if the request has a token or if the request has an associated username
         if(!req.headers.cookie){

            console.log('no cookies were found')

            var token = jwt.sign({user_token_name:req.body.user_name},app.get('superSecret'), {
                expiresIn: 1 *100 *60 // expires in 1 mintue can be what ever you feel is neccessary
            });
             //make a token and attach it to the body
             // req.body.token = token // this is just placing the token as a payload
             res.cookie('austin.nodeschool' , token,{ maxAge: 100000, httpOnly: true }) //this sets the cookie to the string austin.nodeschool
         }
        if(req.body.user_name){
             next()
         }else{
             res.send('request did not have a username').end() // this is here because my middleware also requires a username to be associated with requests to my API, this could easily be an ID or token.
         }
    },function(req, res, next) {
//    console.log(req.headers)  this is here to show you the avilable headers to parse through and to have a visual of whats being passed to this function
            if(req.headers.cookie){
                console.log(req.headers.cookie) //the cookie has the name of the cookie equal to the cookie.
                var equals = '=';
                var inboundCookie = req.headers.cookie
                var cookieInfo = splitCookie(inboundCookie,equals) //splitCookie is a function that takes the inbound cookie and splits it from the name of the cookie and returns an array as seen below.
                console.log(cookieInfo)
               var decoded = jwt.verify(cookieInfo[1], app.get('superSecret'));

                console.log(decoded)
                // You could check to see if there is an access_token in the database if there is one
                // see if the decoded content still matches. If anything is missing issue a new token
                // set the token in the database for later assuming you want to       
                // You could simply check if it's expired and if so send them to the login if not allow them to proceed through the route. 
            }
    next()
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I am not sure I follow you.If I understand correctly the redirect causes all the user data in the session to be deleted?This seems to defeat the purpose session middleware. Also If you check around 42:20 in the [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvviEA1pOXw) he clearly retrieves the session-cookie data after he hits the `/dashboard` route. Apologies again if I am missing something but I am still confused why my code throws `undefined` for `session_state` yet the code in the tut doesn't despite being fundamentally the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: @mikeym When you hit the route in your request do you see session storage in the browser developer console, under resources?

Comment: No nothing is showing up in resources > session storage. But that's what I expected since the `/dashboard` GET is returning `undefined` for the session_state in the node console log. How can I fix that and make the session_state accessible in `/dashboard` route? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your front-end doing? You are attaching the session to the request and responding with a redirect. You didn't attach the session to the response so the front-end doesn't get a session token to store in the browser. You need associated client side code to handle the session response and store the session token in the browser `// Save data to sessionStorage`

`sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`

`// Get saved data from sessionStorage`

`var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');`

Comment: @mikeym I thin I found the line that was messed up.

 `// sets a cookie with the user's info
        req.session.user = user;`

You're using res.session_state = user in your login.

Comment: @mikeym where's the code that sets the cookie? the code you have only passes the information to the session but doesn't attach it to the cookie like the tutorial.

Comment: If you take a look at `app.use(sessions({..` code snippet at top of my question this is where I assume all the cookie config is being done. I'm aware of how to set up manually like you suggested but would prefer to stick to the middleware in the tut and solve the problem in context of my question. He uses `req.session.user` in the tut but that seems to no longer work. That's why I'm using `session_state` instead. That seems fine so  can't see what else I might have missed. Thanks again for help!

Comment: Also notice there isn't anything session related attached to the `res` before the redirect to `/dashboard` in the tutorial code. So it seems unlikely that's where the bug lies.

Comment: @mikeym What does your cookie resources look like? The session is being stored in the cookie and not being stored in the window.sessionStorage. you should see the information in the cookie resources in browser developer view.

Comment: There is nothing at all being stored client side. Cookie and session resources are empty which is the core problem. It seems there is something missing / misplaced in the middleware config. I am just trying to figure out what it could be. Like I say, everything looks identical to the tut code and I've gone through it several times so I'm at a bit of an impasse.

Comment: Thanks for the extra code effort. I'll continue to try to fix the original problem with `client-session` implementation - as I say I'd really like to get it working and still feel it's something simple I've overlooked. If that doesn't help I'll give your suggestion a try. Cheers again!